# Confusion about Newline Interpretation in Command Line Echo with Double Quotes

Tags: linux, command-line, echo, double-quotes

I've been learning about command line expansions and substitution, including path name expansion and command substitution. In my studies, I came across the concept of controlling these expansions using double quotes. While experimenting with these concepts, I encountered a behavior that I'm having trouble interpreting.

When I use the command `echo $(cal)`, the output seems to ignore the newlines and is displayed as a single line:

```
August 2023 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa 1 2 3 4 ...
```

However, when I use double quotes like this: `echo "$(cal)"`, the output is correctly formatted with newlines:

```
    August 2023
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
      1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31
```

From my understanding, using double quotes appears to render the newline characters (`\n`) correctly in the `echo "$(cal)"` command.

However, what confuses me is that when I try a similar approach with other characters, such as `A\nB`, using the command `echo "A\nB"`, the output does not interpret the newline character and instead displays it as literal text:

```
A\nB
```

I discovered that I need to use the `-e` switch, like this: `echo -e "A\nB"`, to achieve the expected behavior:

```
A
B
```

Could someone please explain why the behavior differs between these two cases? Why does `echo "$(cal)"` correctly interpret newline characters within double quotes, while `echo "A\nB"` requires the `-e` switch for the correct interpretation?

I appreciate any insights or clarifications you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no newline characters in `"A\nB"`. C-style escape sequences aren't interpreted inside single quotes or double quotes. Backslash can be used in double-quoted strings to escape special characters like `$` so they're treated literally, but `\n` has no special meaning and is interpreted literally.

To make a string using C-style escape sequences, use `$'string'`.

```
echo $'A\nB'
```

will print

```
A
B
```

The `-e` option to `echo` tells the `echo` command to interpret escape sequences inside the string when it's printing.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing this fact. But I still do not know why the double quotes solves the issue in the command echo "$(cal)" , If $(cal) will return bunch of English letters and some '\n' escape sequences in between, then it is equivalent to echo "A\nB"

Comment: Double quotes prevent word-splitting in the command output. Word-splitting converts all whitespace sequences to a single space, so newlines are turned into spaces.

Comment: Exactly, double quotes consider the space, tab, and new line characters as part of the text not delimiters or separators. But what I want to make sure of if $(cal) returns its results like "xyz \n abc \t" or not?

Comment: It's not returning `\n`. It's returning actual newline characters, just like you see when you just run the command normally. And the quotes prevent those from being replaced with spaces.

Comment: What seems to be confusing you is that you think `\n` is a newline. It's not a newline, it's an escape sequence interpreted by some programming languages or commands, and replaced with newline.